Property is used before being assigned
I have a class with a property that gets assigned in the constructor. The property is then used in an immediately invoked function. Typescript gives an error, indicating the property is used before being assigned:
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor() {
        this.greeting = 'Hello';

        (async () => {
            console.log(this.greeting); // Property 'greeting' is used before being assigned.
        })();
    }
}

TypeScript Playground
I can't see any situation where the property is used before assignment. Is there a way to convince TypeScript of this?

This seems like a bug - notice it works when the IIFE isn't async. Still, you should avoid starting asynchronous side effects in the constructor anyway

@Bergi I've found an issue that describes the problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38929
